Trigger the specific workflow after PR approval
I have a mono repo in github and using the github actions to run the build/deployment pipeline.
I use the path filter on pull_request to run the related workflows on the PR.
name: Workflow Service A
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - "services/serviceA/**"
      - "***.md"
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]
jobs:
  unit-test-serviceA: 
   
  deploy-serviceA:
    if: github.event.review.state == 'APPROVED'
    steps: ...


name: Workflow Service B
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - "services/serviceB/**"
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]
jobs:
  unit-test-serviceB: 
   
  deploy-serviceB:
    if: github.event.review.state == 'APPROVED'
    steps: ...


If i create a PR for services/serviceB/package.json, Workflow service A skips to run since the path doesnt match and Workflow service B unit-test runs. But once the pr is approved, both Workflows trigger the deploy-service step.
I want to run only deploy-serviceB in the workflow after the pr is approved since the pr only contains the file change for serviceB and not service A
I am using
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]


this does trigger the deploy-ServiceB after the PR is submitted (approved) but since I have this trigger in all workflows, all the deloy-service(A-Z) are getting triggered. How can I limit it to just the same PR and the related files

you don't need the pull_request_reivew trigger and can remove the if condition as well, this will kick off the unit test when pull request created, if you only want unit test to start after pull request merged then update it from on pull_request to on push
name: Workflow Service A
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - "services/serviceA/**"
      - "***.md"
jobs:
  unit-test-serviceA: 
  if: github.event.review.state == 'APPROVED'
  deploy-serviceA:       
    steps: ...


added the workflow template here

@SudinShakya I have edited the answer, hope that helps

I need to trigger the deploy only after approval.
